# Rails-4 custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am experimenting with approaches to providing user menus.  As a prototype I ended up with this sort of code in routes.rb. What I would like to know is there a more compact means of providing the same effect without losing too much clarity?

```
  get( 'ag',
    :action         => :ag,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/ag',
    :action         => :ag,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ag',
    :action         => :ag,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ag/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ag/main_menu' )

  get( 'ap',
    :action         => :ap,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/ap',
    :action         => :ap,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ap',
    :action         => :ap,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/ap/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ap/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ap/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ap/main_menu' )

  get( 'ar',
    :action         => :ar,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/ar',
    :action         => :ar,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ar',
    :action         => :ar,
    :controller     => 'navigation/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/ar/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ar/main_menu' )

  get( 'navigation/ar/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ar/main_menu' )

  get( 'menu/currencies',
    :action         => :index,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ag/currencies_menu' )
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you can group all of your routes that use a similar controller in blocks like so:

```
controller 'navigation/main_menu' do
  get 'ag', :action => :ag
  get 'menu/ag', :action => :ag
  get 'navigation/ag', :action => :ag
  get 'ap', :action => :ap
  get 'menu/ap', :action => :ap
  get 'navigation/ap', :action => :ap
  get 'ar', :action  => :ar
  get 'menu/ar', :action => :ar
  get 'navigation/ar', :action => :ar
end

get( 'navigation/ag/journals',
    :action         => :journals,
    :controller     => 'navigation/ag/main_menu' )

controller 'navigation/ap/main_menu' do
  get 'menu/ap/journals', :action => :journals
  get 'navigation/ap/journals', :action => :journals
end

controller 'navigation/ar/main_menu' do
  get 'menu/ar/journals', :action => :journals
  get 'navigation/ar/journals', :action => :journals
end

get( 'menu/currencies',
  :action         => :index,
  :controller     => 'navigation/ag/currencies_menu' )
```